# Extract XML tag with namespace

Tags: sql, xml, plsql, xml-namespaces

I need to extract a XML tag value as in the code below.

`set serveroutput on
declare
    lv_xml     varchar2(500);
    xmlstring  XMLTYPE;
    lv_val     varchar2(10);
BEGIN
    lv_xml :=
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TestMain xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <testTag1>VAL 1</testTag1>
        <testTag2>VAL 2</testTag2>
        <testTag3>VAL 3</testTag3>
    </TestMain>';
    xmlstring := XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(lv_xml);
    SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(fd), 'testTag2')
        INTO lv_val
        FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(xmlstring.EXTRACT('TestMain'))) f,
            TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(VALUE(f),
                                   'TestMain/testTag2'))) fd;
    dbms_output.put_line('Val: '||lv_val);
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
           dbms_output.put_line('Error: '||SQLCODE||' '||SQLERRM);
    END;
/`

When I am running it, I am getting an exception `ORA-01403: no data found`.

I found that, if I remove the XML namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`, then it is working fine. But, the XML stream from which I will extract values will be in this format(that is, it will contain a namespace).

Is there any way to be able extract value with xmlns present?

Comment: A 10 second search finds the documentation for [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions051.htm) that indicates that it can take a further optional parameter called `namespace_string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are:

```
declare
    lv_xml     varchar2(500);
    xmlstring  XMLTYPE;
    lv_val     varchar2(10);
BEGIN
    lv_xml :=
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TestMain xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <testTag1>VAL 1</testTag1>
        <testTag2>VAL 2</testTag2>
        <testTag3>VAL 3</testTag3>
    </TestMain>';

    xmlstring := XMLTYPE.CREATEXML(lv_xml);

    SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(fd), '.')
    INTO lv_val
    FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(xmlstring.EXTRACT('/TestMain', 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'))) f,
        TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(VALUE(f), '/TestMain/testTag2', 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"'))) fd
    ;

    dbms_output.put_line('Val: '||lv_val);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       dbms_output.put_line('Error: '||SQLCODE||' '||SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

And for the code readability sake you can write the particular inside `select` as

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(xmlstring, '/TestMain/testTag2', 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"')
INTO lv_val
FROM dual;
```

or even more readable (though functionally not 100% identical)

```
lv_val := xmlstring.extract('/TestMain/testTag2/text()', 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"').getStringVal();
```