# extractvalue from xmlns oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-namespaces

this code return null and how can i extract  `012019-122019`  from period ?

```
with qwe as (
select  xmltype('<singleAggregatePaymentResponse xmlns:ns7="http://www.mtszn.kz/services/PersonCotracts/schemas">
                  <ns7:isEspPayer xmlns="http://www.mtszn.kz/services/PersonCotracts/schemas">true</ns7:isEspPayer>

                  <ns7:periods xmlns="http://www.mtszn.kz/services/PersonCotracts/schemas">
                     <period>122019</period>
                     <period>112019</period>
                     <period>102019</period>
                     <period>092019</period>
                     <period>082019</period>
                     <period>072019</period>
                     <period>062019</period>
                     <period>052019</period>
                     <period>042019</period>
                     <period>032019</period>
                     <period>022019</period>
                     <period>012019</period>
                  </ns7:periods>

               </singleAggregatePaymentResponse>')xml
               from dual
               )

              select
              extractvalue(value(x101_1),'/period') iou,
               xml

                from qwe q,
                     table(xmlsequence(q.xml.extract('//period')))(+) x101_1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract XML tag with namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806248/extract-xml-tag-with-namespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both extractvalue and xmlsequence are deprecated.

You can do this with xmltable instead:

```
select x.period
from qwe q
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.mtszn.kz/services/PersonCotracts/schemas'),
  '//period'
  passing q.xml
  columns period varchar2(6) path '.'
) x;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=39684d0589555f596f05c04e1682e0a6)

As your XML only has a single namespace I've declared that as default. With more than one, or just if you prefer it, you can name it instead:

```
select x.period
from qwe q
cross join xmltable(
  xmlnamespaces('http://www.mtszn.kz/services/PersonCotracts/schemas' as "ns7"),
  '//ns7:period'
  passing q.xml
  columns period varchar2(6) path '.'
) x;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=00d4cf069c1f5a86addaa6ca62f8370f)